# Drop down stops working after Material UI tags are applied

Tags: angular, material-ui

Seems like a pretty easy one, though it's got me stumped.

This is working:

```
   <select (change)="onStatusChange($event)">
          <option value="0">--{{ hello.status }}--</option>
          <option value="pending" href="pendingHello()">Pending</option>
          <option value="running" href="startHello()">Running</option>
          <option value="completed" href="completeHello()">Completed</option>
        </select>
```

But, the Change event is not retained after I apply Material tags. That is the Status remains the same in the Material version:

```
      <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select (OnSelectionChange)="onStatusChange($event)">
            <mat-option [value]="pending" href="pendingHello)"
              >Pending1
            </mat-option>
            <mat-option [value]="running" href="startHello()"
              >Running</mat-option
            >
//there are more options but stopping at 2 for example purposes
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Ideally, I'd like to pull from an existing service, but for now this is MVP. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you sure `<mat-option [value]="pending" href="pendingHello)" >` is correct?

Comment: You're right, It should be pendingHello()....  It is correct in my local file. I went through and removed proprietary wording from the snippet before I posted it on StackOverflow. In that process, I accidentally deleted part of the parentheses.

Comment: I have also tried (SelectionChange) and (Change) to no avail.

Comment: and there is not any `href` attribute for mat-option

Comment: Ah. How would I work in the functions then?

Comment: @Dewww Have you checked posted answer does it helped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `(selectionChange)` and use `value` not the `[value]` if your mat-option is hardcoded:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select (selectionChange)="onStatusChange($event)">
        <mat-option value="pending">Pending1
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option value="running">Running</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
onStatusChange(event: any) {
  if (event.value == 'pending') {
    // Run function a
  }
  else if (event.value == 'running') {
    // Run function b
  }
}
```

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ts7f6j-5peshg)

Answer (score 1):

From **component.html** we will pass the selected value to **component.ts** of drop-down on **change event**. And we will get that value in **onStatusChange()** function.

**component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
     <mat-select (change)="onStatusChange($event)">
         <mat-option value="pending"> Pending1 </mat-option>
         <mat-option value="running">Running</mat-option>
     </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**component.ts**

```
onStatusChange(event: any) {
  if (event.target.value == 'pending') {
    // Run function a
  }
  else if (event.value == 'running') {
    // Run function b
  }
}
```

Comment: As you define [value]="pending". actually the [ ] braces are used to bind property. and here we have static data so we are working with simple value attribute.          
example:  value="pending"